# Recommended items limit ​for a FlatList

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a FlatList with 20,000 records and a question came up.

What is the recommended limit to be loaded at once into a FlatList?

And after that is it recommended to use an Infinite Scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading like 20 items at once and then infinite load is a good way. But you need to optimize your flatlist (remove clipped subviews, set item layout manually, handle batchs, ...)

More infos https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration

Example

```
<FlatList
    ref={(ref) => {this.searchListRef = ref}}
    data={this.state.search_list}
    renderItem={this.renderSearchItem}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
    onEndReached={(infos) => this.searchMore(infos)}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.8}
    numColumns={2}
    removeClippedSubviews
    initialNumToRender={6}
    updateCellsBatchingPeriod={100}
    maxToRenderPerBatch={6}
    windowSize={10}
    onScroll={(e) => this.handleSearchScroll(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)}
    getItemLayout={(data, index) => (
        {length: 316, offset: 316 * index, index}
    )}
    ListEmptyComponent={<View>...</View>}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{marginBottom: 10}}></View>}
    ListFooterComponent={<View>...</View>}
    ListHeaderComponent={<View>...</View>}
/>
```